# How to pass form-data of body tag of URL using volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

How can I pass the data to form-data of body tag of URL in Volley ? here I show you screen shot which I tried with multiple request but not worked.

please help me.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use getParams method to add body parameters to volley request

```
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
// the POST Body parameters:
if (pack.getParams() != null && pack.getParams().size() > 0) {
    params = pack.getParams();  
    return params;
}
return super.getParams();
```

}

Pack is wrapper class that contains address, bodyparams, passwords and more.

Create a `Map<String, String>` and put your body parameters inside it.